# Spring embedded DB schema not found issue

Tags: spring, junit, hsqldb

I am using embedded HSQLDB in my JUnits. It is throwing

```
SQL state [3F000]; error code [-4850]; invalid schema name:info
```

when it executes query following query

```
select db.id, db.name,info.desc from user_db db,user_info info where db.user_id = info.user_id and info.active = 'Y' and db.dept = info.dept(+)
```

the above query runs fine in oracle but not in embedded HSQLDB

please let me know what is wrong in this.

Comment: This error is never returned for the query that you reported. The query that is actually sent to the database is likely to formatted differently.

Comment: Sorry i missed a left outer join in that query as db.dept = info.dept(+), so i am updating it to above query